# How to populate an array with indexOf

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I'm trying to populate an array with the output of my for loop.
In this case, I'm trying to push every result where indexOf does not return -1 in that showArray.
Here's an example of li I want to push in the array.

```
<li class="student-item cf">
    <div class="student-details">
        <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/12.jpg">
        <h3>soline leclercq</h3>
        <span class="email">soline.leclercq@example.com</span>
    </div>
    <div class="joined-details">
           <span class="date">Joined 05/12/14</span>
   </div>
</li>
```

Here is the Javascript

```
var showArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < eachStudent.length; i++) {
        var studentName = document.getElementsByTagName("h3");
        var studentInfo = studentName[i].innerText;
        var filter = inputString.value.toUpperCase();

        if (studentInfo.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) != -1)  {
            showArray.push(eachStudent[i]);
        } 
       console.log(showArray);               
    }
```

So far, the showArray.push(eachStudent[i]) is not working, it's not printing the items to the array. My goal is to fill and empty that array dynamically as the user types in the search bar.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: So where does your code exactly fail? Have you debugged each line? What is inputString? What is eachStudent?

Comment: var studentInfo = studentName[i].innerText; looks suspicious because the index is potentially not in sync between eachStudent and the collection returned by grabbing the h3's